# Jquery css selector using regular expressions

Tags: jquery, regex, css-selectors

I have a **DYNAMICALLY** generated Navigation div

```
<div id="WebPartWPQ9" >
 <table class="xm-ptabarea">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="" class="tab"><a href="/somelink.aspx">Overview</a></td>
    <td nowrap="" class="tab"><a href="/anothersomelink.aspx">Financials</a></td>
    <td nowrap="" class="tab"><a href="/somemorelink.aspx">Newsfeed</a></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Since there are **no unique IDs**, using jquery, i want to be able to attach an event to the "financial" tab link (using regular expressions selectors maybe?)

The value of the link will always be "Financials"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's super easy to select that `<a>` element using the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
var $financialsLink = $('#WebPartWPQ9').find('td.tab > a:contains(Financials)');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#WebPartWPQ9 a:contains(Financials)')
```

Comment: You are missing the `live` part.

Comment: @Sarfraz, what live part? The OP said that he wants to attach a click handler to a dynamically generated elements and that he needs to find the corresponding element. He doesn't mention anything about regenerating those elements dynamically once the click handler is attached, that's why I didn't talk about any `live` part. It would be unnecessary but of course it will depend on the exact scenario.

Comment: for my scenario, LIVE wouldn't be necessary as no regeneration is happening after the page has been loaded. Nice to learn about 'live' though as i didn't know about it before.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is dynamically generated, you can [use `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to handle events on elements created after the DOM loads.

```
$('#WebPartWPQ9 td.tab a:contains(Financials)').live('click', function() {
    // run code
});
```

Or if the `#WebPartWPQ9` is present when the page loads, I'd probably [use `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

```
$('#WebPartWPQ9').delegate('td.tab a:contains(Financials)', 'click', function() {
    // run code
});
```

Both of these use [the `:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to target the one with "Financials".

Comment: @Bears - I certainly did. Thanks. :o)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) filter selector and [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method like this:

```
$('.tab a:contains("Financials")').live('click', function(){
  // your code...
});
```

Comment: i don't think quotes around Financials are necessary

Comment: @Jason: Yes it would work but it is good practice because you need to specify this for spaced strings. Also jquery docs use quotes.