# Parse css3 selectors with regex (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, css-selectors

If someone has seen this question before, please link, perhaps I am searching the wrong things. I get nothing but results for parsing css files. Basically, I have an array of selectors, something like

`[".thislink", "#myid"]`.

I'm looking to pass any string selector formatted like css3 selectors, ex:

`a.thislink:not(.ignore)[href^=http://]`

into a .match and split it out into an array of selectors, ideally:

`[a, .thislink, :not(.ignore), [href^=http://]]`

that I can loop through. I would then use that same breakdown on any :not() selectors to get a second array of "not", which I can match against my original array of individual selectors.

Tag, class, ID, attr, and :not selectors should be all I need. I can figure out how to break down the `[attr=val]` and `:not(selectorshere)` myself, I think.

PS:
I know it would be easy to match my original array values in the string selector, however, I don't *actually* have an *array* of selectors. It would take several paragraphs to explain why exactly I'm doing it this way, so just trust me, I can't do it =)

Comment: All attempts to write a regex myself have so far ended in misery. If I happen to stumble into the solution, I will of course post it here =)

Comment: Take a look at some of the questions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex+css-selectors

Comment: You may have seen these, but just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481749/matching-css-selectors-with-a-javascript-regexp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781219/jquery-css-selector-using-regular-expressions, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668057/regex-to-extract-only-selectors-from-css-file may be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case you won't succeed in finding a sufficient regex, may I suggest a JavaScript parser generator like [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/)*. There's an [online version](http://pegjs.majda.cz/online) of PEG.js that allows you to tinker with the grammar, then download the parser once satisfied with the result.

[ * ] PEG - [Parsing Expression Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar)

For help with the grammar you should consult the <strike>[W3C's working draft on CSS3 syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax)</strike> [W3C's recommendation on Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar).

I took the time and played around and came up with a reduced grammar for a single selector (element/id/attr/class/pseudo). You'd want to go over it and refine it here and there, probably.

```
/*
 * PEG.js grammar
 */
start      = element? hash? (class / attr / pseudo)*
element    = '*' / ident

ident      = i:(nmstart) j:(nmchar*) {return i + j.join('');}
hash       = h:('#' ident) {return h.join('');}
class      = c:('.' ident) {return c.join('');}
attr       = a:('[' (b:[^\]]+ {return b.join('');}) ']') {return a.join('');}
pseudo     = p:(':' function) {return p.join('');}

nmstart    = [a-z] / nonascii
nmchar     = [a-z0-9-] / nonascii
function   = f:(ident '(' body ')') {return f.join('');}
body       = b:[^\)]+ {return b.join('');}

nonascii   = [\x80-\xff]
_          = [ \t\n\r]+ {return '';}
```

Comment: The Syntax module is pending a rewrite for compatibility with the latest developments; in the meantime, the Selectors 3 grammar is already fully specced and tested: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar In particular, notice that the current Syntax draft has no production for pseudo-elements with double colons. Not much has changed otherwise though.

Comment: @BoltClock The questioner particularly mentioned the `:not()` pseudo-element. I tailored the (admittedly far from being standard compliant) grammar specifically to his needs. Anyway, thank you for the link.